# Meaning of $g_d^r$ in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, notation, definitions

As an editor I often encounter the symbol $g_d^r$ as a noun.  I tried googling but I only get papers where the symbol is used without a definition.  Can someone supply a reference to a definition?  Examples of usage: "Koszul cohomology groups of $g_d^r$s on singular nodal curves"; "any other basepoint-free $g_h^1$ [...] is composed with the given $g_d^1$.

Comment: Sorry for the non-research question but I figure this is the one place where I'm sure to get an accurate answer.

Comment: I had the raw TeX in the title in order to facilitate searches.  Is that not kosher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I understand, a $g_d^r$ is a linear system of dimeansion $r$ and degree $d$. Basically, these give you maps to $\mathbb{P}^r$ of degree $d$. The simplest example is of course hyperelliptic curves; these are the same as a $g^1_2$.

The reference that I have for this is Harsthorne, Algebraic Geometry, p. 341.

Comment: And if Hartshorne used a notation, you can bet a lot of other people are using it too, after learning from him.

Comment: That is the notation for a linear system, as you say.  However, these do not all give maps (there is the issue of base locus).  Precisely, it is a pair of an invertible sheaf of degree $d$ and an $r+1$-dimensional subspace of the vector space of global sections.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: It is an old notation, far predating Hartshorne.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't really suggesting that his was the first usage, just the one that I have on hand.

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  (Re Jason's comment: Hartshorne calls the notation "classical" in the passage where he defines it.)